# Is there a way to have all options in the admin panel expanded all the time? (magento 2.1)

Tags: magento-2.1, admin-panel

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to have all sub-options loaded in the expanded view all the time?

For example, every time I need to work with a category in the category tree, all of its config options are always collapsed. I would LOVE if there was a way to see all the options in default expanded view mode (all the time). It sounds ridiculous, but the amount of unnecessary clicks is getting really annoying.